# My mesh deforms when I shade smooth

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edges, subdivision-surface

I am modelling a character but wherever I bridge edge loops between hands, feet and arms my mesh doesn’t look good at all when I apply subdivisions or if I shade smooth. I have removed doubles and set scale and rotation of all objects to zero but nothing works. An answer would be greatly appreciated, thanks![image][image][image]

Comment: You need to learn topology, for which there's plenty written on this site and elsewhere.  You want all convex, relatively planar, relatively square quads, relatively evenly sized, with no 6+ poles, and 3 and 5 poles placed on the most planar parts of your mesh.  Try doing an image search on "3D topology" and study what you see.

Comment: i have good topology with all of the categories that you said. i am familiar with this. I will upload a topology image. However I have all quads no 6plus poles. I only have this problem when i bridge edge loops and fill in edge loops. Thanks. I am following the video tutorial on the youtube channel Blender Arthttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySZnHBbthrE&list=PLY4NaOmLmvHbbP9GneJsIxQWz3uR__m3S&index=2

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org)

Comment: Some of your normals are probably going the wrong way. Try selecting all in edit mode then select `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I really appreciate this. Thanks ever so much